# How to define default preferences (prefpane)

Tags: firefox, xul, xulrunner, thunderbird, thunderbird-addon

I've successuflly created a custom prefpane for my application (in thunderbird) and defined some preferences.

At the moment, **the values in my prefpane are empty by default**. However, when I do enter/select and save them, everything is good and they get written into the default database.

```
    <preferences>
        <preference id="myextension.settings.autosync_time"
                    name="myextension.settings.autosync_time"
                    type="int"/>
        <preference id="myextension.settings.autosync_server"
                    name="myextension.settings.autosync_server"
                    type="string"/>
    </preferences>
```

How can I predefine values to my preferences (eg. `autosync_time = int(60)` and `autosync_server = string(dlc://mydlc.com)` for my application ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are packaging an extension, you put a JavaScript file with default preferences into the [`defaults/preferences` directory](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Building_an_Extension#Defaults_Files):

```
pref("myextension.settings.autosync_time", 60);
pref("myextension.settings.autosync_server", "dlc://mydlc.com");
```

If you are packaging a XULRunner application or changing Thunderbird the same file goes into the `defaults/prefs` directory of the application.